# Nextjs Image Component - Remote Images

Tags: next.js, host

I am very new to the nextjs and have come across the Image component issue. I also checked around and it seems that there are similar questions but none of them has the given scenario.

I am trying to load image from the remote source via Image component. The documentation saying that you should adjust your next.config.js file to allow remote images. Since I am using next 13.0.3 version I am using images.remotePatterns property. Despite this fact I am still getting an error of hostname not being configured.

Can you please suggest what I am doing wrong and how to overcome that problem?

Br,
Aleks.

next.config.js

```
images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'swiperjs.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/demos/images/**',
      }
    ],
  },

Usage:
        <Image
          src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg"
          className={styles.swiperslideimg}
          alt="test" width={400} height={400}/>
```

**Error:**
Invalid src prop (https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg) on `next/image`, hostname "swiperjs.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
See more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

Answer (score 4):

Try to leave just that:

```
images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        hostname: 'swiperjs.com',
      }
    ],
},
```

Answer (score 0):

That configuration should work. Note that you have to restart the development server by rerunning `yarn run dev` or `npm run dev` for these configuration changes to take effect.

Comment: Yes, I did restart the server without any luck to overcome the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found the solution i was using
**Notus NextJS**
which had a slightly older version of nextjs so i ran

```
npm outdated
```

and updated the package.json and ran

```
npm run install:clean
```

Comment: Updated the packages but still no luck. Failing with the same issue.